# sed command creating unwanted duplicates of file with -e extension

Tags: regex, bash, macos, shell, sed

I am trying to do a recursive find and replace on java files in a directory using a shell script. It works, but it is hiding all the files, and creating duplicates with a -e extension

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.java")
do sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' $file
done
```

From my understanding, the -e is optional - but if I do not provide it I get the following error on every file it finds

```
sed: 1: "./DirectoryAdapter.java": invalid command code .
```

Any clue as it what is happening here? For reference I am on Mac OS X running El Capitan

Here is a before and after screenshot of the directory after running the script. The replaced files still exist, they are hidden?

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

On OSX sed (BSD) `sed` requires an extension after `-i` option. Since it is finding `-e` afterwards it is adding `-e` to each input filename. btw you don't even need `-e` option here.

You can pass an empty extension like this:

```
sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g' $file
```

Or use `.bak` for an extension to save original file:

```
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' $file
```

Comment: excellent. I suspected that is what was happening but didn't realize I could pass in an empty extension. thanks so much

Comment: I thought I was being clever by trying to combine the options, so I was using something like `sed -iE ...` and was getting a bunch of files with `E` attached to the end of them. Took me a while to see the correlation, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer works for OSX but causes issues if your code is run on both GNU and OSX systems since they expect `-i[SUFFIX]` and `-i [SUFFIX]` respectively.

There are probably two reasonable solutions in this case.

1. Don't use -i (inplace). Instead pipe to a temporary file and overwrite the original after.
2. use perl.

The easiest fix for this I found was to simply use perl. The syntax is almost identical:

`sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' $file`

->

`perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' $file`